# Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver equivalent in Unity.Mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I had this piece of code working below in my .NET 4.5 App:

UnityConfig.cs

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<a_interfaces.IAMessageRepository, ARepository.AMessageRepository>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc5.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();      
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var _repo = (a_interfaces.IAMessageRepository)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(a_interfaces.IAMessageRepository));
    }
}
```

I now need to target .NET 4, I downloaded / installed Unity.Mvc4 (version 1.2). I get the following error on this line:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);

The type or namespace name 'WebApi' does not exist in the namespace 'Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Does anybody know what the equivalent code for .NET 4 would be?

Comment: Late joining but just my 2c: Give the following a try

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new global::Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);